# Caught exception evaluating: h.advertiseHeaders(response)

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm getting the following error in Jenkins:

```
Aug 18, 2015 3:34:06 PM hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression evaluate
WARNING: Caught exception evaluating: h.advertiseHeaders(response) in /adjuncts/2804cc2f/lib/layout/breadcrumbs.js. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hudson.Functions.advertiseHeaders(Functions.java:1848)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:258)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:104)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
        at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:74)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.parser.EscapingExpression.evaluate(EscapingExpression.java:24)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ExpressionScript.run(ExpressionScript.java:66)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:81)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyRequestDispatcher.forward(JellyRequestDispatcher.java:55)
        at hudson.util.ErrorObject.doDynamic(ErrorObject.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:297)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:160)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.dispatch(MetaClass.java:361)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:685)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:799)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:587)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:218)
```

Jenkins is on RHEL, Java 7, version 1.598. I'm baffled as I'm trying to port a configuration that works in a production environment onto another server that is essentially an identical configuration.

**Update #1**

The other error when I load Jenkins. My config has usesSecurity to false, uses LDAP, managerPassword isn't null or empty.

```
org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initialDirContextFactory': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'managerPassword' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Manager password must not be empty or null.
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:246)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:43)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:906)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:806)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:221)
```

**Update #2**

Jenkins version is actually 1.529.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed **1.598** over **1.529** and restarted.